# When to use multiple preferences files?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I usually use one preference XML file to store all app-wide data. Now I wonder if this is a wrong way to do. When should I use multiple preference files?

After checking my sdcard I found many preference XML files and it seems that many apps use a single preference file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the same approach as with software development in general.

[High Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and [Low Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). 
Meaning to tie preferences to the module that is responsible for them.

Of course it doesn't matter if we only talk about ~10 values.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple preference files might be useful to manage settings across multiple users.  For instance, if I were writing a Twitter client that allowed multiple Twitter accounts, I could generate a separate preferences file for each individual account.

Comment: Good point. So each app which has multiple users should have multiple preference files as well. We'll see if the other will agree upon this statement.

Answer (score 1):

I have never run into a situation where I chose to use anything but the default `SharedPreferences` for storing preferences. As long as you don't use overlapping names for different preferences, it should be fine.

That said, I also don't see any real downside to using multiple files, as the user should never see them anyways, and I would think any performance hit would be extremely minor, unless you are storing complicated things in preferences.

Comment: Frankly, it is easier to use one file that's why I am asking when not to use it :)